# Why 0x90 byte is always at top of my file?

Tags: debugging, ghidra, hex, byte-code

Note: Not sure if this kind of question belongs here but as long as this won't fit anywhere else this site is the closest.

Back to the topic, I have a python file which I obfuscated it and anytime I want to turn this into executable using `pyinstaller` there's a `0x90` byte at the beginning of file which it can't be decoded using `UTF-8`. When I run the program it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 500, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 481, in djxvCOWAMQFNXLmkmwHopqHMWeJWqRRfaTYhtVQhEjhYQByjCUhjZmlyRVkSKqsEcxYRXketUHcQvObBfTQifGMfTOEsxpDzumWrevMKrXWYeXWOqinkNlbvZDoeaQMo
  File "test.py", line 236, in CjpiLgqGSPHXaLfOKvPztQfChQlzklDoKWuieQOqmnPEnVxqRophKppuTPUSrlAdiWNiSOwcKqyDZoQSJsvmVPUVLFIQvRZbwSFHZQdLkwgXSoPoFJbjsZnrLKWkjKnZ
  File "codecs.py", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Not sure how do I deal with this, I have tried different naming of variable and still the same thing. Can someone help me a bit with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the file that causes the problem in a (hex) editor if it is really a python source file? Please post the first bytes of that file (best in hex). What obfuscator have you used?

Comment: Yes, I used one online because New Hex Editor didn't display well the bytes. I used `Intensio Obfuscator` as an obfuscator. [link](https://i.imgur.com/1AEVcez.png) this is a link to a screenshot I have captured because this online editor couldn't let me copy some hex bytes

Comment: Apparently it was an encoding error on my file before obfuscating it. the question should be closed now.

Comment: you can add an answer with the explanation and accept it

Comment: ok sure I might do it because someone else might find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of problems are related to the `encoding` of your script/program. My specific problem was related that `0x90` byte on my file was a `latin` character which `UTF-8` couldn't recognize. On top of my file I wrote `# -- coding: latin-1 --` and it was fixed. For anyone curios the little pest was this character `È` at byte `0x90`.